# Is it possible to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString with Javascript which references local files?

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

I want to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to run a javascript which references local files (in this case css files, but potentially js files too) which are on the device (in the Documents folder I guess?)...

```
 NSString *theJS = [[NSString alloc]
 initWithString:@"javascript:(function()
{the_css.rel='stylesheet';
the_css.href='the_css.css';
the_css.type='text/css';
the_css.media='screen';}
)();"];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:theJS];
```

How would I get this to work? It works fine if I use an external css file, like

```
the_css.href='http://www.website.com/the_css.css';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've done in the past is used this code when loading the HTML

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath];

[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8 " baseURL:baseURL];
```

This will pass the bundle location as the base url which should cause your relative urls to work correctly. Of course you don't have to use this exact `loadData` method, there are various overloads. Just get the `baseUrl` in there and you should be good to go.

If all else fails you can use something like:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file.css" ofType:nil]]
```

And inject that into the page with some string replacements or whatever. Bit hacky though.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this.

```
NSString *cssPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"the_css.css"];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:cssPath];


 NSString *theJS = [[NSString alloc]
 initWithFormat:@"javascript:(function()
{the_css.rel='stylesheet';
the_css.href='%@';
the_css.type='text/css';
the_css.media='screen';}
)();",baseURL];
[cssPath release];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:theJS];
```

Hope this will solve the problem.