# Load UIWebView with a CSS local file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, css, ios, uiwebview

I'm looking for a way to load my UIWebView with a local CSS file that should affect on the UIWebView's loadRequest.

For the clearness:
I have an UIWebView that I loadRequest it with a website url.
I also have a local CSS file that should affect this loadRequest url.

I want to load this CSS file onto the UIWebView.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893715/;) appears to have one or two answers that may help you.

You need to load the local CSS (using a method not unlike @Shrey uses, but looking for your CSS file), and somehow inject it into the page, and the only way appears to be to use:

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:someJavascriptToInjectCSS];
```

and some clever Javascript to modify the page to add the CSS in.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.  I have used this method to inject stuff into pages, so it does work, but I don't know Javascript well enough to write the code to inject your CSS into the page.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the link on the answer - now edited.  There is an answer on that page which appears to do what you want, in including the js.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to apply custom css files on UIWebView that loads sites such as Google or should I give up for this option?

Comment: Yes, you can use the answer in the SO question - the answer I am referring to is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893715/is-it-possible-to-use-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-with-javascript-whic/1895864#1895864    This answer shows loading of a CSS from a local file and injecting it into the web-view.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Swift version.

Load the css file on the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method and use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`.
Credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457316/2780252)

```
 func loadWebViewStyles() {
        guard let cssPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("theme", ofType: "css") else {
            return
        }

        let loadStyles = "var script = document.createElement('link');  script.type = 'text/css'; script.rel = 'stylesheet'; script.href = '\(cssPath)'; document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);"

        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(loadStyles)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

`[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];`

Comment: don't think that's going to do what OP is asking for.  For starters it is a local CSS file they want to load, not an html file, then they want to inject the CSS into a page that doesn't reference it.

Comment: Then try using webview delegate methods.